# Why is a timeout error not caught by WebExceptionStatus.Timeout?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am using HttpWebRequest/Response to call WEB API's, this works and I have a try/catch block to handle errors which mostly works, but the problem is one specific error causes my try/catch to crash.

This error

> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
>
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.WaitForCreatedConnectionAsync(ValueTask`1 creationTask)
>
> at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result()
>
> at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.DecompressionHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>
> at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

is not being handled by this code in my catch clause and I dont understand why

```
 catch (WebException we)
            {

                JObject emptyObject = null;

                if (we.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                {
                    log.LogInformation($"xxx_V2 HttpWebRequest suffered a timeout for URL: {apiUrl} at: {DateTime.Now}");
                }
...... Removed non relevant code
}
```

This means that code further down will crash as they rely on headers being present in a response but of course I dont have a response since it timed out, thats why I am trying to catch it above.

Answer (score 0):

As I can see that the exception being raise is of type of  `**System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException**` and exception handling you did for the type of  **`WebException`**  is one of the reason that you code is not getting executed in the catch block . Try to optimize you code in such a way that if you are explicitly handling any type of exception other than `WebException` then have a catch block with base class of exception which is like below:

```
Catch(Exception ex) {

}
```

The WebException class is thrown by classes descended from WebRequest and WebResponse that implement pluggable protocols for accessing the Internet.You can read about this more in details in below doc:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webexception?view=netframework-4.8

Hope it helps and let me know if you need any help implementing it.

Then all your unhandled exception will be handled in this block

Comment: But the exception is caught by my clause, its just doesn't have the we object set somehow, because I am trying to use it to get header info but of course its a timeout, so it does enter the block but with we not set if that makes sense, if I simply return directly in my catch everything works fine so I know it enters the block.